# Is there an equivalent of (this) inside of IF statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Although this could be easily achieved with pure CSS, the forum software I'm working with writes inline styles into the HTML which I need to override, or in this case, change dynamically with jQuery.

I have a list menu, and I want the anchor within the li.active element to have a black background. Here's where I am with it.

```
if ( $('#community_app_menu li a').parent().hasClass('active')) {
    $('#community_app_menu li a').css({
        'background-image': 'none',
    'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
 });
 }
```

Obviously, this targets all the "#community_app_menu li a" elements, but I can't use $(this) inside of IF.

Is what I want to do even possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The more jQuery-ish way would be to [**filter**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) out the elements you don't want to target (in other words, only select the elements you want to manipulate). This would be the generic approach:

```
$('#community_app_menu li a').filter(
    return $(this).parent().hasClass('active');
}).css({
    'background-image': 'none',
    'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
});
```

But we can do better:

If the `li` element is actually the parent of the `a` element, add the class to the selector:

```
$('#community_app_menu li.active > a').css({
    'background-image': 'none',
    'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
});
```

Even if the `li` element is not the parent, you could use a single selector instead of `.filter`:

```
$('#community_app_menu li .active > a').css({
    'background-image': 'none',
    'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
});
```